# Long review time in CS discipline

Tags: journals

It has been an year since I submitted my research paper to a journal in Concurrency (Computer Science). The status says it is still under review. Is this typical of journals in this discipline?

Answer (score 7):

While six months is not unusual in computer science (where journals have little urgency), a year is too long to go without any response.  Write to the editor, and ask **politely** when you should expect a response.